# How can I change a Google spreadsheet cells text using app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a find and replace function for my spreadsheet. I want the function to find the string 'Shaun' and replace it with something else.

Here is my code

```html
function findAndReplace() {
  let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();
  let found = values.map(function(row) {
    return row.reduce(function(acc, cell, ind) {
      if(typeof cell !== 'string'|| cell.indexOf('Shaun') === -1) {
        acc[ind] = cell;
        return acc;
      }
      acc[ind] = cell.setValue('Hello');
    

      return acc;

    }, []);
  });
  
 range.setValues(found);
}
```

I'm getting the error "TypeError: cell.setValue is not a function". How would I correctly rewrite this so that it replaces the cells value with Hello?

Comment: take a look at [TextFinder().replaceWith](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceWith(String))

Comment: Next issue. I've created a trigger for the function by assigning the script to a button image. Sadly the button image doesn't run the script on my tablet. Any ideas why/if possible?

Comment: You could make it a webapp

Comment: I've done that but it still doesn't work. Could you please go into more detail?

Comment: Keep working on it until it does

Comment: I mean I've made it a web app but the shape which on a web browser triggers the script, doesn't work on the app. How do I trigger the web app?

Comment: By writing to the deployment url.  I often use querystrings to control the process

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing this row:

```
acc[ind] = cell.setValue('Hello');
```

To this:

```
acc[ind] = cell.replace('Shaun', 'Hello');
```